# Cassandra timeout during write query but entry present in Datebase

Tags: cassandra, timeout, bigdata, datastax, cassandra-3.0

We are using Cassandra 3.0 on our system. For insertion in the db, we are using the Datastax C# driver.

We have a query regarding the timeout and retry during insertion. We faced an instance where a timeout during insert was thrown yet there is that entry present in the database. All are settings are default in the Cassandra.yaml file as well as in the driver.

How can we know the actual status of the insert even if there is a timeout? If there was a timeout thrown, how could possibly the insert have gone through ahead? Whether the insert was successful or there was some default retry policy in place that was applied, we don't have any tangible answer on it currently and we need to know exactly about that.

How do we make sure that the status of that insertion was actually successful/failed with or without the timeout?

Comment: paste your code!! without it we cannot know the issue

Answer (score 1):

A write timeout is not necessarily a failure to write, moreover it's a notification that not enough replicas acknowledged the write within a time period.  The write will still eventually happen on all replicas.

If you do observe a write timeout, it indicates that not enough replicas responded for the configured consistency level within the configured [write_request_timeout_in_ms](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/configuration/cassandra_config_file.html?highlight=yaml#write-request-timeout-in-ms) value in cassandra.yaml, the default being 2 seconds.  Keep in mind however that the write will still happen.

The coordinating Cassandra node responsible for that write sends write mutations to all replicas and responds to the client as soon as enough have replied or the timeout is reached.  Because of this, if you get a `WriteTimeoutException` you should assume the write happened.   If any of the replicas are down, the coordinator maintains a [hint](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_about_hh_c.html) for that write, which will be delivered to the replica when it becomes available again.

Cassandra also employs [Read Repairs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesReadRepair.html) and Operators should run recurring [Repairs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesManualRepair.html) to help keep data consistent.

If your operations are [idempotent](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.4/manual/idempotence/), you can simply retry the write until it succeeds.  Or you can attempt to read the data back to make sure the write was processed.  However, depending on your application requirements, you may not need to employ these strategies and you can safely assume the write did or will happen.

Please note on the other hand that `unavailable` errors (i.e. `Not enough replicas available at consistency level X`) indicate that not enough replicas were available to perform a write and therefore the write is never attempted.